# error with NSSring

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm very new to objective-c and I'm getting a basic error and unsure on how to fix it.

```
  for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
        resultText.text = sym.data; //sym.data = 0012044012482
        [self phpPost:(int)sym.data];
        break;
    }
}

- (void)phpPost: (int)barcode {
    NSString *theValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", barcode]; //problem line
    labelScan.text = theValue;
    //labelScan.text = @"Barcode scanned";
}
```

when i use @"%@" the text of the label is correct (0012044012482), but when i use @"%d" it isn't (random number every time i restart the app). I would like to use @"%@" (or something that works) but for some reason xCode is giving me an error. and I'm unsure on how to fix the error.

The error is:

> Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int'

In the end I plan on having that code (sym.data) written to a MySQL database using the POST method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some thinking while I was at work today, and I figured out that an INT isn't going to work for me. if I make that object to an int, I would loss some data that is vital to what I'm doing. eg. object=001234 int=1234. I need the zeros. So, in the end, I'm keeping it an object (string) and just passing it into the function.

Here is my code after I got it working correctly.

```
for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
        resultText.text = sym.data;
        [self phpPost:sym.data];
        break;
    }
}

- (void)phpPost: (NSString *)barcode {
    labelScan.text = barcode;
    //labelScan.text = @"Barcode scanned"; //My custon label
}
```

Thanks, everyone for your responses. Your answer will not go unused. I'm sure I'll be needing this information here soon.

O, if you see that I did this wrong, or not the correct way, please make a comment and tell me .

Answer (score 3):

You can't just convert it to an `int` by casting if it's an object (which it must be if the `%@` format specifier isn't causing a crash).

Assuming from the fact that you're assinging it directly to a label's `text` that it's an `NSString`, you should either change the parameter type of `phpPost:`

```
- (void)phpPost: (NSString *)barcode {
    labelScan.text = barcode; 
}
```

or extract the `intValue` before passing `sym.data`:

```
 [self phpPost:[sym.data intValue]];
```

and then use the proper `%d` format specifier in `phpPost:`.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I'm still very new to objective-c, very new, about a week of tutorials. The reason I was casting it to an int was because I'm going to store that barcode into a MySQL database. labelscan is just a label I'm using for development, it will not be in the final release. So, with the time I had at work to think about my code, I've found out that using it as an int isn't going to work for me. I would loss vital info in that barcode, eg. object=001234 int=1234. So, I'm keeping it as an object and your code worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your barcode isn't an `int`, it is an `NSString`. Instead of doing `(int)sym.data`, pass in `[sym.data intValue]`. That should correctly convert it to an integer.

The reason you get a random number is because you can't just cast a string object to a primitive data type :)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I figured it out and making it an int wasn't the way to go. I'm keeping it an object. but if you may can you tell me why (int)sym.data isn't the right way of doing it and why [sym.data intValue] is?

Comment: It has to do with pointers. The NSString is A pointer to a string object, and thus it is basically just a memory address. When you cast it directly, you just get the value of the memory location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type `sym.data` is, but it is likely a pointer to an object, and not the value itself. You cast that pointer to `int`, so when you are using `%d` you are effectively printing the memory location of the object. That is why it changes each time you run the program (Objective-C let's you do this without any warnings - something to watch out for).

To fix this, either extract the integer value you need from the `sym.data` object using it's properties; or pass the object as a pointer. For instance, you could try calling your method like this:

```
[self phpPost:sym.data];
```

And then change your method to be:

```
- (void)phpPost: (id)barcode {
    NSString *theValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", barcode];    
    labelScan.text = theValue;
}
```

Comment: Well, I had some time to think about my question while I was at work and I might have a problem. If I convert the object to an int. I'll lost the zeros in front of my barcode. eg. object= 001234, int=1234. so, I need to keep it an object of find out a different way of doing this.

Comment: With me being new to objective-c with does the "(id)" mean in - (void)phpPost: (id)barcode? I haven't seen that before.